# Prove that $\sqrt{I}=I$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ideals

> Let $f(x,y)=y^2-x^2-x^3$ and consider the ideal $I=(f)$ in $\mathbb C[x,y]$. I want to show that the radical ideal $\sqrt{I}$ is equal to $I$.

Any help? I've tried an approach using the division algorithm in 2 variables but became too messy. Is there any general approach one can follow to prove that $\sqrt{(g)}=(g)$ for $g \in k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the ring here? $\mathbb Z[x,y]$, $\mathbb C[x,y]$? Some arbitrary $R[x,y]$?

Comment: Sorry, $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Comment: $\mathbb C[x,y]$ is a unique factorization domain. So you need to show that it is square-free. Do you know a way to show that a polynomial in $y$ is square-free?

Comment: Much more than that, the polynomial is irreducible, as you can see from the picture. Map $\Bbb C[x,y]$ into $\Bbb C[t]$ by sending $x$ to $t^2-1$, $y$ to $t^3-t$, and check that the kernel is your ideal.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thank you for your comment but no, I do not know a way to show that a poynomial in $y$ is square-free. In a one variable polynomial one could look at the derivative, but here we have a two variable polynomial...

Answer (score 0):

An expansion of my comment:

$I$ is a radical ideal of $R$ if and only if $R/I$ has no nilpotents. But in this case, $\Bbb C[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$ is better than that, it’s an integral domain. You’re just using the congruence $y^2\equiv x^3+x^2\pmod I$, and you should think of this as looking at the extension $\Bbb C(x)\bigl(\sqrt{x^3+x^2}\,\bigr)\supset\Bbb C(x)$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand: why is $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$ an integral domain?

Comment: Because it’s injected into the field $\Bbb C(x)(\sqrt{1+x}\,)$.

Comment: Hmm, so you're using that there exists an injective map from $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$ to $\mathbb{C}(x)(\sqrt{x^3+x^2})$, is that right?

Comment: Yes, precisely. In fact, let me take the opportunity to say that the concept of the radical of an ideal comes into its own when the associated subset is not a hypersurface, as in your example, but something of dimension $n-2$ or less. Like the intersection of the $x$-axis with the curve $y=x^2$. Now the ideal is the one generated by the two separate things, so $(y, y-x^2)=(y,x^2)$, clearly different from its radical.